# Spark Structured Streaming not restarting at Kafka offsets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

We have a long running Spark Structured Streaming query which is reading from Kafka, and we would like this query to pick up where it left off after the restart.  However, we have set the `startingOffsets` to "`earliest`" and what we see after restarts is that the query reads from the start of the Kafka topic again.

Our basic query looks like this:

```
  val extract = sparkSession
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "server:port")
    .option("subscribe", "topic")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .load()

  val query: StreamingQuery = extract 
    .writeStream
    .option("checkpointLocation", s"/tmp/checkpoint/kafka/")
    .foreach(writer)
    .start()
```

We see the checkpoint directory getting created correctly and with the offsets we expect in the offset files.

When we restart we see a message like:

```
25-07-2017 14:35:32 INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:231 - Setting newly assigned partitions [KafkaTopic-2, KafkaTopic-1, KafkaTopic-0, KafkaTopic-3] for group spark-kafka-source-dedc01fb-c0a7-40ea-8358-a5081b961968--1396947302-driver
```

We are telling the query to start at "`earliest`" but the documentation says:

[This only applies when a new Streaming query is started, and that resuming will always pick up from where the query left off.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

Shouldn't this mean that restarting our application results in the query resuming where it left off?

Setting the "`group.id`" for Kafka is not allowed with Spark Structured Streaming.   See this: [Note that the following Kafka params cannot be set and the Kafka source will throw an exception.](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

I tried adding `queryName`, in case that was being used to identify the query across runs but it did not have any effect.

We are using Spark 2.1 on YARN.

Any ideas on why this does not work or what we are doing wrong?

**UPDATE WITH LOGS:**

[From the Driver](https://pastebin.com/9Vdy8wAM)

[From the Worker](https://pastebin.com/RtiaBhTz)

Comment: The log means nothing. Spark will create a unique id as the group id for each run. You can use `StreamingQuery.recentProgress` to print the recent progress and it should contain the offset information.

Comment: That doesn't help much. It runs fine. It just starts at the first offset instead of the last read when restarted.

Comment: The previous run just has one batch? If so, before 2.2.0, Spark will always rerun the last batch in the previous run.

Comment: It seems to me that Spark doesn't pick up the checkpoint dir at all when it restarts.  I see no diff in 1) removing the checkpoint dir and running the application and 2) stopping the application after it has processed all messages and then restarting with a checkpoint dir that looks good.  In both cases it starts at the earliest Kafka message.  I assume I am doing something wrong but can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the logs?

Comment: Do you have `"spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation"` set on your `SparkSession`? You can use either `queryName` or `checkpointLocation` options to checkpoint the query between runs. Also, as pointed by @zsxwing, since Spark uses WAL for checkpointing, it will reprocess the last checkpointed batch after restart.

Comment: Can you try setting `startingOffsets` to `latest`?

Comment: According to the docs, the checkpointing directory "has to be a path in an HDFS compatible file system"

Comment: @himanshuIIITian - using latest would mean I would lose messages during restarts if the checkpoint dir is not being used.

Comment: @danieln - The directory specified in the code snippet is a HDFS filesystem.

Comment: @nonsleepr I think you are referring to Spark Streaming and we are using Spark Structured Streaming here.

Comment: @PatrickMcGloin, I am talking about Structured Streaming. It's not documented, but if `checkpointLocation` is not set on the query then it would use `"spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation"` + `queryName` as a checkpointing directory. My comment about WAL is still relevant.

Comment: New logs don't say much. Try setting `log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution=DEBUG` in your `log4j.properties` and look for `DEBUG StreamExecution: Stream running from` and `DEBUG StreamExecution: Resuming with committed offsets:` in the log.

Comment: @nonsleepr checkpointLocation is set on the query, and the directory and contents are created as expected.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: No, though I did not see the issue again so I think I was doing something wrong, not sure what

Comment: I noticed something similar.  Are you setting the maxOffsetsPerTrigger.  I think when you do this it can compute the initial offsets incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why are you saying that the checkpoint directory gets created again. Are you deleting it after your initial run and then resuming it?

So, just to be clear ".option("startingOffsets", "earliest")" setting will read from the very beginning when you start the query for the first time. 
And consider that something went wrong, and the stream stopped. You fix it and start the stream once again (without deleting the checkpoint directory) the stream should start from the offset where it had stopped previously.

In case if you have deleted the checkpoint directory and then resumed the stream obviously it won't be having any history of offsets read (as you have deleted the checkpoint) and thus will start from the very first (earliest) offset that is available on kafka.

Comment: "You fix it and start the stream once again (without deleting the checkpoint directory) the stream should start from the offset where it had stopped previously. " - What if the offset that is checkpointed is not available in the topic anymore?